# g suite directory contacts not deleted

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-contacts-api, google-workspace

I have used the G Suite shared contacts directory (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/)  to delete a bunch of contacts.  All contacts were deleted from an API point of view (the API no longer returns these contacts)

However a few of these "deleted" contacts remain visible in my contacts (contacts.google.com).  When I click on one of these it shows 'The contact was not found'

Anyone had this problem and if so is there any way these 'zombie' contacts can be deleted from Google contacts?

[contact not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iJSf.png)

Comment: Have you tried to report the issue to the [G Suite Admin SDK support](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/support)?

Comment: I did not know about the issue tracker, I have now submitted an issue